# Tell component to destroy state on close

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent that owns a ModalComponent:

```
render(){
return (
  <MyCustomModal
    visible={this.state.displayModal}
    //various properties
  />
);
}
```

`MyCustomModal` has state, say `MyCustomModal.myState`.  When I click save/cancel I want `MyCustommodal.myState` to reset to null.  Currently I have a function to handle this:

```
export function clearFields(){
  //called by onCancel to setState to null
}
```

I'm finding this clearFields() to be difficult to manage.  Can I reset the state of a child in such a way where I don't have to manage the state myself?

In other words is there some way to hook into the component life cycle and tell it to dismount...or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decide if your child component must be mounted or unmounted within the parent component render method. Whenever the render method is called, a virtual DOM is created, and then compared with the actual existing virtual DOM of that component (if there exists any), then if any changes are found, they are applied as appropiate (mounting or unmounting children elements or changing its props, etc).

So you can decide to render the children with a condition in your render method. If the child was already mounted and it has to unmount, its "componentWillUnmount" method will be called and you can execute any clean up code you need in there.

Look at the next code block for an example (or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GonArrivi/L9yuo85s/1/))

```
var World = React.createClass({
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    alert('This component is unmounting');
  },
  render: function() {
    return ( < span > World! < /span>);
    },
  });

var Hello = React.createClass({
  _handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({
      showChild: false
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showChild: true,
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    var childNode = null;
    if (this.state.showChild)
      childNode = ( < World / > );
    return <div > Hello {
      childNode
    } < button onClick = {
      this._handleClick
    } > Click < /button></div > ;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Hello / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```